# Kafka MirrorMaker2 Behavior

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, apache-kafka-mirrormaker

For Example, I have produced 100 msgs to topic T1 in DC1 and around 80 msgs have been mirrored to DC2. In DC1, I have consumed around 90 msgs. Now DC1 goes down and I am consuming from DC2. My consumer request would be to fetch the 91st message. But only 80 msgs have been mirrored. What will happen in this case?

What are configurations to be changed in Mirror Maker2 to make it high availability from DC1->DC2,all messages produced in DC1 should be available in DC2 without data loss.

Answer (score 0):

> My consumer request would be to fetch the 91st message

Actually, it should be 81. The offsets in each DC are unique. If the data isn't mirrored, the consumer will stop, just like a single cluster and a producer that stops working (since that is all it is underneath).

If DC1 is goes down, or is disconnected, that is an infrastructure issue, not a problem that can be solved at the application level. If you want high-availability, then you would need some sort of buffering on DC1, but that can only be reasonably done on network disconnect (and a lot of custom code before restarting MirrorMaker), not a full power-outage.

Comment: Thanks for your inputs. What are configurations changes should be made to make it highly available, All the messages produced in DC1 should be mirrored in DC2 without data loss.

Comment: You don't need to repeat your question. As answered, that depends where your failure is, and cannot be solved by app config.. MirrorMaker2 doesn't guarantee zero data loss